# Can we use Oracle Database directly, without using tools

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to know is there any difference between Oracle and sql developer tools?

Comment: Oracle is a DBMS. SQL Developer is a tool for working with that DBMS. They're nowhere near the same thing.

Comment: Can we use this Oracle dbms directly without   using tools

Comment: What would you do with it without the tools to create databases and tables and stored procedures and so forth?

Comment: @PravinGaddam You would need, at the very least, some sort of client through which you issue SQL to interact with the RDBMS. If not SQL Developer (provided free of charge from oracle) then another client like toad.

Comment: Please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you consider a 'tool.'

The database ships with a couple of command-line interfaces, SQLPlus and SQLcl. Those are both tools, they're not a part of the core database code.

You could also use web interfaces like SQL Developer Web, APEX, EM Express, or Enterprise Manager. Some of those ship with the Database, and EM Express runs out of the database, but those are kind of tools too.

You could write your own program to interact with the database, but you're going to use a JDBC driver or something that supports SQLNet...but then are those drivers, tools?

So my answer to you is, it depends on what you mean by 'tool.'

Can you use the database without SQL Developer, yes.